# ignite default table

Tags: sql, kubernetes, ignite, in-memory-database

I'm using ignite chart in kubernetes, in memory deployment without persistent volumes, how can I configure default tables to be created automatically after restart of all ignite pods?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your issue? What do you expect and what's the actual behaviour? Unless you restart all your pods the dynamic tables should not be terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify them in your `IgniteConfiguration` using Java or Spring XML, via Query Entities mechanism:

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/indexes#configuring-indexes-using-query-entities

In this case all the caches and corresponding tables will be recreated when cluster is started.

Comment: it will create a table? I decid4ed to install gridgain image so they have no shell my only solution is to install it by configuration?

Comment: Yes, it will create a table.

Comment: sql table ? or key value?

Comment: Did you try to read the documentation page that I have linked?